# How to make the maximum of each column 1 and others 0 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with float values. I would like to make the max of each column 1 and all others in the column 0.

Example:

```
1 2 3

4 5 1

7 0 1
```

becomes

```
0 0 1

0 1 0

1 0 0
```

Assume presence of headers and index also.

How do I use the df.apply() method here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to use `df.apply` is to not use `df.apply`.

```
(df == df.max()).astype(int)

   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
```

Comment: Nice answer. but I didn't understand this description "The best way to use df.apply is to not use df.apply". +1

Comment: For max along rows, (df == df.max(axis=1)).astype(int)? But this is transforming the df into a square df and max is not working...

Comment: @vaibhavk I don't see `axis=1` in my answer anywhere... why did you add it? It changes the answer.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah because apply sucks, don't use it.

Comment: @coldspeed, sorry, I figurerd 0 for columns and 1 for rows. Anyway, what should should I do if I want to make the max of each row 1 and others 0?

Comment: @vaibhavk Something like `pd.DataFrame(df.values == df.max(axis=1)[:, None], dtype=int)`?

Answer (score 1):

you can try `pd.get_dummies(df.idxmax(1))`

`df.idxmax(1)` returns pandas.series of the MAX column for each row.

```
df
Out[204]: 
   A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  1
3  7  0  1

df.idxmax(1)
Out[205]: 
1    C
2    B
3    A
```

and then `pd.get_dummies()` will create the dummies Data Frame according to the series of the max values

```
pd.get_dummies(df.idxmax(1))
Out[206]: 
   A  B  C
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  1  0  0
```

Comment: Would be great to get more exposition on your answer (for posterity).

Comment: agree with you. i added explanation to my answer.